# Create azure Action group with azure terraform with json format

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Hi i am trying to create "azurerm_monitor_action_group" based on json format i have
[github_link](https://github.com/sai2202/Krishna/tree/Action_group)
please go through the github link and update me changes which i missed..

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Hi @RahulKumarShaw-MT 
error i am getting is "Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string)."

Comment: Please check this it may help you :https://github.com/avinor/terraform-azurerm-monitor-action-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tried with your code was getting the same error.**
[image]

Solution :

***The reason you are seeing the error is because `jsonencode` returns a string, when `for_each` expects a map or a set. Instead of using `jsonencode`, use Terraform's map directly.***

***You can use this below code for me `terraform plan` is succesful while `terraform apply` getting error as `email` is not valid for me. You can test the same in your enviorment it will succesfully apply for you.***

**main.tf**

```
##############  azurerm provider  ######################################
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.99.0"
    }
  }
}


provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  #   client_id       = var.client_id
  #   client_secret   = var.client_secret

  features {
  }
}
###################

locals {
  our_widgets = {  
   "dashboard1" ={
        "type": "sbns",
        "sme": ["sme1@bechtel.com","sme2@bechtel.com"],
        "tech_support": ["tech1@bechtel.com","tech2@bechtel.com"],
        "primary_support": ["primary@bechtel.com","primary2@bechtel.com"],
        "secondary_support": ["secondary1@bechtel.com","secondary2@bechtel.com"],
        "all": ["all1@bechtel.com","all2@bechtel.com"]
    },

    "dashboard2" ={
        "type": "sta",
        "sme": ["sme1@bechtel.com","sme2@bechtel.com"],
        "tech_support": ["tech1@bechtel.com","tech2@bechtel.com"],
        "primary_support": ["primary@bechtel.com","primary2@bechtel.com"],
        "secondary_support": ["secondary1@bechtel.com","secondary2@bechtel.com"]
    },
    "dashboard3" ={
        "type": "kv",
        "sme": ["sme1@bechtel.com","sme2@bechtel.com"],
        "tech_support": ["tech1@bechtel.com","tech2@bechtel.com"],
        "primary_support": ["primary@bechtel.com","primary2@bechtel.com"],
        "secondary_support": ["secondary1@bechtel.com","secondary2@bechtel.com"]
    },
    "dashboard3"={
        "type": "redis",
        "sme": ["sme1@bechtel.com","sme2@bechtel.com"],
        "tech_support": ["tech1@bechtel.com","tech2@bechtel.com"],
        "primary_support": ["primary@bechtel.com","primary2@bechtel.com"],
        "secondary_support": ["secondary1@bechtel.com","secondary2@bechtel.com"]
    },
    "dashboard5"={
        "type": "postgres",
        "sme": ["sme1@bechtel.com","sme2@bechtel.com"],
        "tech_support": ["tech1@bechtel.com","tech2@bechtel.com"],
        "primary_support": ["primary@bechtel.com","primary2@bechtel.com"],
        "secondary_support": ["secondary1@bechtel.com","secondary2@bechtel.com"]
    }
}
}

############################
##########  Creating ResourceGroup   #######################
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "v-rXXXXXe"
  #location = "westus"

}
##################################
resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "monitor_action_group" {
  #for_each            = local.resource
  name                = "test4574365"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  short_name          = "short-alert"
  dynamic "email_receiver" {
  for_each = local.our_widgets
    content {
      name                    = "Email"
      email_address           = "email_receiver.value.primary_support" # here it is not working 
      use_common_alert_schema = true #Enables or disables the common alert schema
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

For more information you can refer this [***link***](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraform/comments/mpef1e/error_invalid_dynamic_for_each_value_cannot_use_a/)